# Gif animation as a background for a layout

Tags: android-layout

Like iPhone I want to set a gif animation as a background for android layout. is it possible? If yes someone  kindly share  your knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: use https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable or https://github.com/Cutta/GifView

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and also very simple.
First you set or declare main layout is `RelativeLayout`, then inside this main layout set your required layout. 
Both height and width are `match_parent`. 
After you set your gif file XML code which is outside of inside layout and inside of main layout.

Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         *********** here you create your GUI layout *********

    </RelativeLayout>

*************** Here your gif file xml code, here i'm using ex. lib ***********

      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/butterflyanimation"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In here I am using a third party lib to load the gif file and it's build path is

```
 compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
```

Comment: You probably need to explain where pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifTextView comes from as it is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: ya it is third party lib